# Sort by ACF field in the products in my Custom Post Type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

Could you please tell me how to sort my products(it is my custom post type) by the field(see picture) in ACF ?

[image]

Here is my custom field code:

```
    /*******            *******/
/*   CUSTOM POST TYPE     */
/*******            *******/

// Custom Post Type - product
function register_post_product() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'               => __( 'Products', '_tk' ),
    'singular_name'      => __( 'Product', '_tk' ),
    'add_new'            => __( 'Add product', '_tk' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New product', '_tk' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit product', '_tk' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New product', '_tk' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All products', '_tk' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View product', '_tk' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search product', '_tk' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No product found', '_tk' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No product found in the Trash', '_tk' ), 
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => __( 'Products', '_tk' ),
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'supports'          => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail' ),
    'public'            => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_in_menu'      => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive'       => true,
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'produkty','with_front' => false),
    'menu_position'     => 6,
    'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-hammer'
  );
  register_post_type( 'product', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_product' );
```

I made some search in google and I tried to sort it like that:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {
      $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
      $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
      $query->set( 'meta_query','capacity');

      return $query;
}
```

But with no results.

Answer (score 0):

try this below function for pre_get_posts in wordpress

```
<?php
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {

  $query->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'capacity' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' ); // meta_value_num or meta_value
  $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );


  return $query;
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have the blank bage in result

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is `$query->set( 'meta_query','capacity');`

meta_query should be an an array, like

```
array( array('key' => 'capacity', 
             'value' => array(0, 1000), 
             'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
             'type' => 'numeric', 
     ));
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I dont know if I typed it correcly ?

' add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );
function my_get_posts( $query ) {
   $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
   $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
   $query->set( 'meta_query',array(
            'key'     => 'capacity',
            'value'   => array( 0, 10000 ),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ));
   
   return $query;
} '


Because not works :(

Comment: Your code seems correct, it's my bad. I updated the code in the answer, meta_queries are nested arrays. But @shital-marakana 's solution is even better and should work as well. You may be getting a blank page because of an error if WP_DEBUG is disabled in wp-config.php

Comment: It is still something wrong with @Shital-Marakana's solution. I commented two lines:

  `$query->set( 'post_type', 'product' );
  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'capacity' );`

and now the products appear but still unsorted.Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: As I understand only the post list is empty, and the rest of the page is ok, so no php errors, right? Then maybe you can try looking into the database. If you've made sure the products have 'capacity' meta in the _postmeta table, you can check the final sql WP generates. E.g. run `global $wp_query; var_dump( $wp_query->request );` (if it's main query and `global $wp_query` is used) and try to execute it and see why it returns no results. There may be some unobvious conditions like post_status etc.